# Kubernetes - 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' error

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am using ingress-nginx for my kubernetes cluster with AWS tls certificate .

Both the **frontend** and **backend** services are running inside the cluster.

I am **able to view the frontend** but when it interacts with backend it throws the error :

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

> **Ingress nginx**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: ingress-nginx-controller
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
      - www.example.com
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/upload/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: aws-srv
              servicePort: 3000
```

> **Ingress nginx service**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:ap-south-1XXXXX"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.11.1
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.34.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

I am stuck here and unable to take this to production, thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using AWS API Gateway also in this picture , like anywhere before ingress ?

Answer (score 1):

Which URL did you define in backend ? if it's [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), then remove `- example.com` line.

I think you should remove aline in this:

```
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
      - www.example.com
```

Remove : `- example.com` then check again.

OR you keep both hosts:
but reconfigure this :     `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "false"`